# Bundle with browserify programmatically without gulp

Tags: npm, browserify

It is very easy to bundle with the command line, or using gulp :

```
     browserifiedSource
    .bundle()
    .pipe(source('./build/index.js'))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('./'));
```

But this common snippet is using source from `vinyl` package and `gulp`. The command line doesn't needed these.

```
    browserify build/index.js -o dist/index.js
```

How can I bundle with browserify Javascript Api without gulp or vinyl ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do much the same thing, just `pipe` to a standard file stream:

```
const browserify = require('browserify');
const fs = require('fs');

browserify()
    .add('build/index.js')
    .bundle()
    .pipe(fs.createWriteStream('dist/index.js'));
```